# Jquery .scrollTop does not work in a modal box

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use [Venobox](http://veno.es/venobox/) modal window plugin to show photos, comments and subcomments. The form to post subcomments is not visible by default. User must click "Reply", in Spanish "Responder" and then appears the form.

```
a href="#" class="comentario_a" id="0-51-3-1-0">Responder</a>

$(document.body).on("click",".comentario_a",function() { 
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
$("#commentbox"+ID).slideToggle('slow');
$("#ctextarea"+ID).focus();
return false;
});
```

The problem is that in many cases users have to scroll down the page to see the comment form because it appears below the bottom margin. I want page (the content of modal box) to jump up so that user sees the form without scrolling but `.scrollTop` does not work in my modal window.

I tried everything:

```
$("html, body").scrollTop($("#commentbox"+ID).offset().top);
$("#commentbox"+ID).scrollTo(100);
```

etc, etc but can't get it working. I can achieve that the parent page jumps to top but not the content in the modal window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you just want to subtract `100` from the html scrolltop

Try

```
$("html, body").scrollTop($("#commentbox"+ID).offset().top - 100);
```

Comment: When I use this, the parent page scrolls to the top but not the content inside of modal box.

Comment: Suggest you provide a demo that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved that by changing the context from `"html, body"` to the specific modal selector.
So, say your modal has `id="modal"`, use this:

```
$("#modal").scrollTop($("#commentbox"+ID).offset().top);
```